# Bad Method Call - php artisan serve not working - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Estoy usando Laravel por primera vez y seguí un tutorial que completé exitosamente. Todo funcionaba bien, pero cuando intenté ejecutar nuevamente el comando "php artisan serve", no funcionó. Revisé el sitio de error, que es algo mencionado en el tutorial, pero no pude encontrar ninguna información en línea. Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme a resolver este error.

El mensaje del error es el siguiente:

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\tiendaOnline> php artisan serve
PHP Warning:  Module "openssl" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module "openssl" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0

   BadMethodCallException 

  Method Illuminate\Routing\Route::middelware does not exist.

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Macroable\Traits\Macroable.php:112      
    108▕      */
    109▕     public function __call($method, $parameters)
    110▕     {
    111▕         if (! static::hasMacro($method)) {
  ➜ 112▕             throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
    113▕                 'Method %s::%s does not exist.', static::class, $method     
    114▕             ));
    115▕         }
    116▕

  i   Bad Method Call: Did you mean Illuminate\Routing\Route::middleware() ?

  1   routes\web.php:24
      Illuminate\Routing\Route::__call("middelware")
  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteFileRegistrar.php:35
```

El archivo web.php contiene lo siguiente:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController;
use App\Http\Controllers\SessionsController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
})->middleware('auth');

//Rutas Register
Route::get('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'create'])
    ->middelware('guest')
    ->name('register.index');
Route::post('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'store'])
    ->name('register.store');

//Rutas Login y Logout
Route::get('/login', [SessionsController::class, 'create'])
    ->middelware('guest')
    ->name('login.index');
Route::post('/login', [SessionsController::class, 'store'])
    ->name('login.store');
Route::get('/logout', [SessionsController::class, 'destroy'])
    ->middelware('auth')
    ->name('login.destroy');
```

La linea en el fichero vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteFileRegistrar.php se encuentra dentro de la siguiente función, la cual es generada por Laravel y no ha sido modificada por mí en ningún momento.:

```
    public function register($routes)
    {
    $router = $this->router;

    require $routes;
    }
```

---

El error no se corrige comentando la línea de openssl. El problema es con la invocación a los middleware, se queja del segundo en adelante, si los comento funciona correctamente pero necesito que si el usuario está logeado no se muestre las pantallas de login y registro mientras dure la sesión, al igual que cuando realice el logout vuelva a la pantalla de login.

Se que el error no existe en el openssl, lo que se ve de openssl en el error es porque utilizo XAMPP, pero los que no levantan la aplicacion son los siguientes:

```
Bad Method Call: Did you mean Illuminate\Routing\Route::middleware() ?

1   routes\web.php:24
      Illuminate\Routing\Route::__call("middelware")
2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteFileRegistrar.php:35
```

Tiene que ser algo relacionado con el require $routes generado por Laravel.

---

Ya he podido encontrar el problema, reside en el uso de varias veces del mismo Middleware, en el caso de que se utilice para varios Route el mismo Middleware, hay que generar el grupo de los mismos.

Dejo por aquí la solución por si algún usuario lo necesita en un futuro:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController;
use App\Http\Controllers\SessionsController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

//Rutas Middleware guest
Route::middleware('guest')->group( function () {
    Route::get('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'create'])
    ->name('register.index');
    Route::get('/login', [SessionsController::class, 'create'])
    ->name('login.index');
});

//Rutas Middleware auth
Route::middleware('auth')->group( function () {
    Route::get('/logout', [SessionsController::class, 'destroy'])
    ->name('login.destroy');
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('home');
    });
});

Route::post('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'store'])
    ->name('register.store');

//Rutas Login y Logout

Route::post('/login', [SessionsController::class, 'store'])
    ->name('login.store');

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Comenta esta línea en el archivo php.ini

```
;extension=openssl
```

Lo encontré en esta web: https://www.programmersought.com/article/98402483996/

Comment: Esto es Stackoverflow en español. Por favor traduce tu respuesta

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).